# Trying but failing to create multiple hidden HTML <select> dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

> I'm trying to create a submission form which will allow my users to
>   create an asset register list and I'm trying to get input for a
>   location field. The user must first however select a building, then
>   select a floor then finally select a room.
>
> I could include all locations as 's within a single 
>   element, however the list would be massive and ugly. Also, room names
>   are similar across sites so it would be best to keep them in a
>   separate element.
>
> I would like the user to first select a building from a dropdown menu.
>   I would then like another dropdown menu to appear below that depending
>   on their building choice. Once they select their floor choice I would
>   then like a third select dropdown to appear which will then ask them
>   for the room (again depending on the option from the previous select
>   element).
>
> I'm able to show one hidden select list by using an if...else function
>   and simply toggling between block/none but I don't seem to be able to
>   utilise the same technique for the value return on the (previously)
>   hidden select list.
>
> I've included some primitive code. I'm not very experienced with
>   javascript so I've just created a simple if...else statement --with
>   plans to use a switch statement once I can get this proof of concept
>   down.

```
<script>
    function locCheck(choice) {
        if (choice.value == "195"){
    document.getElementById("floor").style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
    document.getElementById("195").style.display = "none";
            }
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function sublocCheck(choice) {
        if (choice.value == "Ground Floor"){
    document.getElementById("room").style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("room").style.display = "none";
            }
    }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="building">
        <span>site*</span>
        <div>
            <select onchange='locCheck(this);'>
            <option value="">-- Select A Site --</option>
            <option value="195">195  </option>
            <option value="123">123  </option>
            <option value="8">8  </option>
            <option value="Off-Site">Off-Site</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="floor" style="display: none;">
                  <span>Floor*</span>
           <div>
            <select onchange="sublocCheck(sl);"> 
            <option value="">-- Select A  Floor --</option>
            <option value="Ground Floor"> Ground Floor</option>
            <option value="First Floor"> First Floor</option>
            <option value="Basement Floor"> Basement Floor</option>
            </select>
                  </div>
    </div>

    <div id="room" style="display: none;" >
                  <span>room*</span>
           <div>
            <select> 
            <option>-- Select A room --</option>
            <option>room1</option>
            <option>room2</option>
            <option>room3</option>
            </select>
                  </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

> > Building (Always visible)
> >
> > > Floor (was hidden, can only be shown/hidden by Building list)
> > >
> > > > Room (was hidden, can only be shown/hidden by Floor or Building list)
>
> If this isn't clear, I'd be glad to explain further. It's pretty late
>   and I'd just like a fresh pair of eyes to look at my code.
>
> thanks in advance,
>
> L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function call is wrong. Fix it to `onchange="sublocCheck(this);"` and it will fix your issue.

Second Problem is the else statement of locCheck the display none shall go to id=floor not id=195

**By the way re-think about your approach. If you unselect the 195, the floor dropdown will hide. then you can't hide the room number dropdown.**

```html
<head>
<script>
    function locCheck(choice) {
        if (choice.value == "195"){
    document.getElementById("floor").style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
    document.getElementById("floor").style.display = "none";
            }
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    function sublocCheck(choice) {
        if (choice.value == "Ground Floor"){
    document.getElementById("room").style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("room").style.display = "none";
            }
    }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="building">
        <span>site*</span>
        <div>
            <select onchange='locCheck(this);'>
            <option value="">-- Select A Site --</option>
            <option value="195">195  </option>
            <option value="123">123  </option>
            <option value="8">8  </option>
            <option value="Off-Site">Off-Site</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="floor" style="display: none;">
                  <span>Floor*</span>
           <div>
            <select onchange="sublocCheck(this);"> 
            <option value="">-- Select A  Floor --</option>
            <option value="Ground Floor"> Ground Floor</option>
            <option value="First Floor"> First Floor</option>
            <option value="Basement Floor"> Basement Floor</option>
            </select>
                  </div>
    </div>

    <div id="room" style="display: none;" >
                  <span>room*</span>
           <div>
            <select> 
            <option>-- Select A room --</option>
            <option>room1</option>
            <option>room2</option>
            <option>room3</option>
            </select>
                  </div>
            </div>
</body>
```